# Resolving image URLs from a Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, android-architecture

To resolve an image URL by width and aspect ratio I need to know the specific image URL schema that my image API uses. The width and aspect ratio is known in my UI module while the schema specification is known in my data module each of which should be agnostic to one another.

So far I defined an `ImageUrlResolver` interface with a resolve method residing in data, that is implemented by an `ImageUrlResolverImpl` that knows how to resolve image URLs provided by the backend. In my dagger `DataModule` I created a method `provideImageUrlResolver` that provides a Singleton instance of the `ImageUrlResolverImpl`.

In order to keep the separation between UI and data layer I would like to implement a `ImageUrlUtil` singleton in my domain layer that should be accessible from an Image Composable residing in my UI layer. However injecting a kotlin object doesn't seem to be an option available with dagger.

I could create a `GetImageUrlResolver` class that can be injected to my ViewModels so I can pass references of `ImageUrlResolver` down to my ImageComposable. As every Screen of my App has images though I would not only have to inject this class into every ViewModel but would also have to pass down the reference the whole layout tree to my Image Composable.

Are there any viable solutions for the problem I am facing?

Comment: Why does your Composable need access to ImageUrlUtil, and what do you want ImageUrlUtil to do? For the purest sake of separation you won't want your UI layer to understand the schema, and that's fine, but by that logic your Composable will need to ask its data layer for a URL given its current width and aspect ratio, and that happens to be the same interface `(url template, width, aspect ratio) => url string` that matches your resolver.

Comment: Only my Composable knows what width and aspect ratio the image should be displayed with. Right now I have a resolveImageUrl method within my ViewModel that I pass down to any Composable that displays images loaded from the network. It works but it is also quite tedious in a complex app. That's why I thought calling an ImageUrlUtil that hold a reference to the specific resolver implementation could be useful.

Comment: Thanks. What problem are you trying to solve with dependency injection here? Will your app ever have multiple implementations of ImageUrlResolverImpl in production, or is this just for testing? If it's likely just for testing, you could have your ImageUrlUtil Kotlin object create and store an instance of ImageUrlResolverImpl that you make available to your Composables, and then you test your Composable by creating a mock or fake ImageUrlResolverImpl that you can use to override the default (via an optional constructor or method argument) so that detail stays out of your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I solved this by using a LocalCompositionProvider that provides a function to resolve image URLs. By default it just returns an unresolved URL. A function to resolve can be provided like this 
`CompositionLocalProvider(LocalImageResolver provides viewModel::resolveImageUrl)` and can be accessed like this `LocalImageResolver.current(url, width, aspectRatio)`.
Could this lead to problems with recomposition?